# Data is passed as null in invoke-webrequest put method

Tags: powershell, put, invoke-webrequest

When I send input to PowerShell put request it throws an internal error.

This is the response I got:

```
   "message": "Internal Error"
   "status": "failed"
```

The code snippet is as follows:

```
$input_data=@"
{
  "share": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
"@
$postParams = @{ INPUT_DATA=$input_data; format="json" }
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method PUT -Body $postParams
```

Comment: Try the following, `$postParams = @{ INPUT_DATA=$input_data }` and specify the content type `$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method PUT -Body $postParams -ContentType "application/json"`

Comment: No still it is not working. Actually for the code I posted output is fine in postman but in chrome it is not working the response text(in chrome) is {share={}}

Comment: Check the HTTP Request payload with fiddler for both postman and chrome.